# String comparison in a batch script for loop

Tags: string, batch-file, for-loop

I'm having issues with a simple piece of batch program in a for loop.

basically, the program should for every file in a folder, if the file name begins with 'LOTTR' it should copy the file to the location Y:\ELCWork1-Rus. if not then it should be copied to Y:\ELCWork2-Oth. I've used 2 if's rather than an if..else for future substring comparisons...

I need to compare an evaluated substring to a fixed value.
In the code below - the logic always fails to match.  I've tried with and without double quotes and set the variable inside and outside the for loop.

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set %c=LOTTR
for %%s in (*.csv) do ( 
   set tmp1=%%s 
   set vt1=!tmp1:~0,5! 
   set vt2=!tmp1:~0,55! 
   set "cmv=LOTTR"
   echo !tmp1:~0,10! 
   echo !vt1!
   echo %%c
   if /I "!vt1!"=="LOTTR" (
       echo "Matches"
       Xcopy !tmp1! "Y:\ELCWork1-Rus"
       )
   if /I NOT "!vt1!"=="LOTTR" (
       echo "No Match"
       Xcopy !tmp1! "Y:\ELCWork2-Oth"
       )

)
```

Comment: Use the extended set syntax to avoid your trailing spaces.`set "tmp1=%%s"` and `set "vt1=!tmp1:~0,5!" `  ...

Comment: Thanks Jeb - that'll sort it

Answer (score 0):

You have put a space after the line `set vt1=!tmp1:~0,5!`. The string becomes "LOTTR " if the file starts with "LOTTR":

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for %%s in (*.csv) do ( 
    set tmp1=%%s 
    set vt1=!tmp1:~0,5!
    if /I "!vt1!"=="LOTTR" (
        echo "Matches"
        Xcopy !tmp1! "Y:\ELCWork1-Rus"
        )
    if /I NOT "!vt1!"=="LOTTR" (
        echo "No Match"
        Xcopy !tmp1! "Y:\ELCWork2-Oth"
        )
    )
```

Comment: excellent - removed all the trailing spaces fro all loines and it works perfectly now - Thanks Jon